# How can I replace NaN values with empty cells in Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, nan

I have a large Pandas dataset in Python with several columns of different data types that all contain some cells that are NaN. My problem is that I want these cells to be empty rather than say 'nan', but I'm not sure how to do it. I can replace the nan-value with an empty string, but then I can't keep the columns the correct data types, as in the example below:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A': ['a', 'b', np.nan], 'B': [1, np.nan, 3], 'C': [np.nan, 2.2, 3.3]})

df_test = df_test.replace(np.nan, '')

df_test = df_test.astype({'A': 'str', 'B': 'Int64', 'C': 'float64'})
```

This just gives

```
TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype
```

Since it cannot convert the empty string to an integer. Is there another way of converting nan-values to actual empty cells instead of empty strings? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't, either revert the operation (`.replace('', np.nan)`) or use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "*empty cells*", use NaNs